# Pygame - Transform screen on mouse movement

Tags: python, math, pygame

I am trying to implement the transformation, where if you are holding down the left mouse button and you move your mouse, the screen will be transformed accordingly. The same thing that happens in [Google maps](https://www.google.com/maps/), the holding and dragging the screen thing. I could not find a function in pygame to transform the screen, something like `screen.transform` so I did this.

I am converting from pixel to cartesian cordinates, and vice versa.

```
x_offset = 0
y_offset = 0

# Cartesian to pixels
def to_pixels(x, y):
    center_x = (WIDTH / 2) + x_offset  # The center of the screen (Width/2) + some transformation in x 
    center_y = (HEIGHT / 2) + y_offset 
    return center_x + x, center_y - y

# Pixels to cartesian
def to_cartesian(pW, pH):
    center_x = (WIDTH / 2) + x_offset
    center_y = (HEIGHT / 2) + y_offset
    return (pW - center_x), -(pH - center_y)
```

The way I am performing the screen transformation is by adding an `x_offset` and `y_offset` basically moving the center.

Now, the **real problem** in the main loop I am storing the mouse position in an array `pos = [0, 0]` and updating every time

```
while 1:
    posX, posY = to_cartesian(*pygame.mouse.get_pos()) # mouse cords to caretsian
    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed(3)[0]:
        # Translate X
        translate = pos[0] - (pos[0] - posX)
        x_offset += translate
        # Translate Y
        translate = pos[1] - (pos[1] - posY)
        y_offset -= translate

    pos = [posX, posY]
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (*to_pixels(0, 0), 20, 20)) # Drawing any shape to visualize
```

The problem is, despite the transformation being smooth, that the mouse cursor, is always be stuck in the `(0, 0)` coordinates of the screen. Wherever i click, it becomes the center.

If you are bored to write the basic `pygame.init()` functions [here](https://pastebin.pl/view/50a1293e) is a working example but instead of `pygame.rect` it uses another shape to better illustrate the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your program does not remember the old offset value.

**[Here is a modified version of your code](https://github.com/Spacha/Pygame/blob/master/Transformation/solution.py)** which works as expected. One solution is that you use a flag `mouse_held` that becomes `True` when mouse is just pressed down and `False` when it's released. This can then be used to save the old offset values so they won't get overwritten when the mouse is pressed down next time.

```py
    # ...

    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed(3)[0]:
        mpos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        # mouse is just PRESSED down
        if not mouse_held:
            mouse_origin = mpos
            mouse_held = True
        
        # mouse is being HELD
        if mouse_held:
            offset_x = old_offset_x + mpos[0]-mouse_origin[0]
            offset_y = old_offset_y +mpos[1]-mouse_origin[1]

    # mouse is just RELEASED
    elif mouse_held:
        old_offset_x = offset_x
        old_offset_y = offset_y
        mouse_held = False

    # ...
```

Also, your `to_pixels` function returned floats which is not very good thing.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, saving the old offset is the key. But what is the  reason for using an if in `if mouse_held`, since it will always evaluate to `True`?

Comment: When the mouse is just pressed down, `mouse_held` is still `False`It's there to differentiate the "just pressed down" event from "holding down continuously". Because when the mouse is clicked, we need to save the location where that happened – and also to detect when the button is released (`mouse_held` is `True` but mouse is not pressed anymore --> it was just released). I think you could also use `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP` event for that.